# ArchLinux, need to allocate space to web server

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, arch-linux

my filesystem looks like this...

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             7.3G  1.5G  5.4G  22% /
none                  2.0G  120K  2.0G   1% /dev
none                  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1              99M   12M   83M  13% /boot
/dev/sda4             103G  188M   98G   1% /home
```

My webserver is in /srv/http/, right now it's living off of space from /dev/sda3/.  I expect to be doing a project on my web server which involves uploading larger amounts of files which will take up more space.  Will it automatically start using drive space from /dev/sda4/?  I doubt it will, so if not, how can I allocate space from /home to my web server at /srv/http (or if not just /)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it will not use space for /dev/sda4.  You will probably have to repartition.  The simplest solution is probably to shrink the /dev/sda4 partition, and use the extra space to create a new partition, which you will then mount `/srv` on.

You can do both these steps in [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php).  You will have to boot from [a LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).  As always when partitioning, it's best to do a backup first.